# Why am I not accurately detecting very obvious digits with tesseract?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to detect numbers with tesseract but I'm struggling despite the images appearing straightforward (minimal/no background noise & clear single line). I've created a minimal test case and posted the results from my own.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VintQ.jpg) is a selection of example numbers where I have removed the red channel, converted the grayscale and applied a binary threshold.

On top of this pre-processing I've tried combinations of increasing the scale, bluring the images to remove noise, dialating and eroding the images as different PSM and OEM modes.

test case:
[image]

output:

```
img:                       2 22419 2330
blur:                      23 22419 226 16 333 03
Erode: 
Dilate:                    22 22419 266330
Morphology:                2 22419 24
BlurMorphology:            2222419 26 116
BlurErode: 
BlurDilate:                23 22419 226633 3 03
BlurErodeDilate:           22 22419 226 16 3343 03
BlurErodeDilateMorphology: 2222419 26 116
```

desired ouput:

```
23 22 4 19 2 2 6 11 6 3 3 14 3 4 4 4 10 3 11 9
```

```
from pytesseract import pytesseract
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Change the working directory to the folder this script is in.
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\tesseract')

path_to_tesseract = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract

def remove_noise(image):
    return cv2.medianBlur(image,5)
 
def dilate(image):
    kernel = np.ones((4,4),np.uint8)
    return cv2.dilate(image, kernel, iterations = 1)
    
def erode(image):
    kernel = np.ones((4,4),np.uint8)
    return cv2.erode(image, kernel, iterations = 1)

def morphology(image):
    kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    return cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

def boundingBox(name, img):
    hImg, wImg, _ = img.shape
    h, w, c = img.shape
    boxes = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img, config = "_char_whitelist=0123456789") 
    for b in boxes.splitlines():
        b = b.split(' ')

        x, y, w, h = int(b[1]), int(b[2]), int(b[3]), int(b[4])
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, hImg - y), (w, hImg - h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, b[0], (x, hImg - y + 13), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (50, 205, 50), 1)

    cv2.imshow(name, img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

def findNumbers(img, name):
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config = "-c tessedit"
            "_char_whitelist=' '0123456789"
            " --psm 3 "
            "lang='eng'")
    # Print Results
    print(str(name) + ": " + str(text))

    
img = cv2.imread('testData2.png')
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# Stage 1 Pre Processing
Blur = remove_noise(img)
Erode = erode(img)
Dilate = dilate(img)
Morphology = morphology(img)

# Stage 2 Pre Processing
BlurErode = erode(Blur)
BlurDilate = dilate(Blur)
BlurMorphology = morphology(Blur)

# Stage 3 Pre Processing
BlurErodeDilate = dilate(BlurErode)

# Stage 4 Pre Processing
BlurErodeDilateMorphology = morphology(BlurErodeDilate)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# Stage 1 Output
findNumbers(img, "img")
findNumbers(Blur, "blur")
findNumbers(Erode, "Erode")
findNumbers(Dilate, "Dilate")
findNumbers(Morphology, "Morphology")
# Stage 2 Ouptut
findNumbers(BlurMorphology, "BlurMorphology")
findNumbers(BlurErode, "BlurErode")
findNumbers(BlurDilate, "BlurDilate")
# Stage 3 Output 
findNumbers(BlurErodeDilate, "BlurErodeDilate")
# Stage 4 Output
findNumbers(BlurErodeDilateMorphology, "BlurErodeDilateMorphology")
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# Stage 1 highlighting detection
boundingBox('img', img)
boundingBox('Blur', Blur)
boundingBox('Erode', Erode)
boundingBox('Dilate', Dilate)
boundingBox('Morphology', Morphology)
# Stage 2 highlighting detection
boundingBox('BlurErode',BlurErode)
boundingBox('BlurDilate',BlurDilate)
# Stage 3 highlighting detection
boundingBox('BlurErodeDilate',BlurErodeDilate) 
# Stage 4 highlighting detection
boundingBox('BlurErodeDilateMorphology', BlurErodeDilateMorphology)
```

Comment: You can try image invert.

Comment: As in white on black rather than black on white?

Comment: show us the intermediate results, those you get after filtering and before OCR. -- the "shortest code necessary" please, a [mre].

Comment: After filtering and before OCR is my test case I posted in the OP. This is the shortest code possible showing what I've done.

Comment: ok so tesseract doesn't know the font, so you need to perhaps train it on that. -- not an OpenCV problem. the preprocessing looks good enough.